# Djangoのeditformにて保存が出来ない為、どの点でエラーが発生しているか知りたい。

Tags: python, html, django

お世話になります。

サッカーゲームの選手閲覧作成を目指して、作成を行っております。

現在、管理画面上で登録した初期値情報をHTMLのform上で出力する所までは行っているのですが、
保存登録でsubmitボタンを押しても、保存されず、画面遷移しないという事象が起こっております。

もしお分かりの方が居られましたら、
どの点でエラーが生じているかアドバイス頂けると幸いです。

宜しくお願いいたします。

参考文献：
https://blog.narito.ninja/detail/33/
https://blog.narito.ninja/detail/35

・今わかっているエラー内容：
保存登録のsubmitボタンを押下後、formのformationformsetが画像無しで表示されている。

保存登録のsubmitボタンを押す前
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

保存登録のsubmitボタンを押下後
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**form.py**

```
class PlayerCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model =  Player
        exclude = ('skill',)


SkillInlineFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Player, Player.skill.through, fields='__all__', can_delete=False
)

AbilityFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Player, Ability, fields='__all__', extra=0
)

FormationFormSet = forms.inlineformset_factory(
    Player, Formation, fields='__all__', extra=0
)
```

**views.py**

```
def editformview(request, pk):
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=pk)
    form = PlayerCreateForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=player)
    skillformset = SkillInlineFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=player)
    abilityformset = AbilityFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=player)
    formationformset = FormationFormSet(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=player)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid() and skillformset.is_valid() and abilityformset.is_valid() and formationformset.is_valid():
        form.save()
        skillformset.save()
        abilityformset.save()
        formationformset.save()
        return redirect('mainapp:index')

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'skillformset': skillformset,
        'abilityformset': abilityformset,
        'pk':pk,
        'formationformset': formationformset,
    }

    return render(request, 'mainapp/editform.html', context)
```

**editform.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="card card-profile my-5 mx-auto">
    <div class="card-body">
      <form method="post" action="{% url 'editform' pk %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">選手プロフィール編集</h5>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table class="profile_table mb-4">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">選手画像</th>
              <td class="data">{{ form.player_image }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">リリース日</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.date_field }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">選手名</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.player_name }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">初期能力/最大能力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col">{{ form.initial }}</div>
                  <div class="col">{{ form.maximum }}</div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">最大レベル</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.level }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">レアリティ</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.rarity_group }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ポジション</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.position_group }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">所属リーグ</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.league_group }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">所属クラブ</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.club_group }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">国名</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.country }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">年齢</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.age }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">身長</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.height }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">利き足</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">{{ form.dominant_foot }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">プレースタイル</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ form.playstyle_group }}
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">能力編集</h5>
        <table class="profile_table mb-4">
          <tbody>
        {{ abilityformset.management_form }}
        {% for ability_form in abilityformset %}
            <tr>
              <th class="header">オフェンスセンス</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.offense_sense }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ボールコントロール</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.ball_control }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ドリブル</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.dribble }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">フライパス</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.fly_pass }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">決定力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.determining_power }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ヘディング</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.heading }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">プレースキック</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.place_kick }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">カーブ</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.curve }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">スピード</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.speed }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">瞬発力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.instantaneous_power }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">キック力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.kick_power }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ジャンプ力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.jumping }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">フィジカルコンタクト</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.physical_contact }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ボディコントロール</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.body_control }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">体力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.physical_fitness }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ディフェンスセンス</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.defense_sense }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ボール奪取</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.take_the_ball }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">アグレッシブネス</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.aggressiveness }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">GKセンス</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.gksense }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">キャッチング</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.catching }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">クリアリング</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.clearing }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">コブラシング</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.cobraging }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">キック力</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.kick_power }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ディフレクティング</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.deflectiveing }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">逆足頻度</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.reverse_foot_frequency }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">逆足頻度</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.reverse_foot_accuracy }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">コンディション安定度</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.condition_stability }}
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="header">ケガ耐性</th>
              <td class="data form_wrap form_wrap-2">
                {{ ability_form.injury_resistance }}
              </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">フォーメーション編集</h5>
        <table class="profile_table mb-4">
          <tbody>
          {{ formationformset.management_form }}
          {% for formation_form in formationformset %}
            <tr>
              <th class="header">フォーメーション画像</th>
              <td class="data">{{ formation_form.formation_images }}</td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <h5 class="card-title text-center">スキル編集</h5>
        <table class="profile_table mb-4">
          <tbody>
            {{ skillformset.management_form }}
            {% for skill_form in skillformset %}
            <tr>
              <th class="header">スキル</th>
              <td class="data">{{ skill_form.skill }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning btn-block" type="submit">登録する</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**今わかっているエラー内容への対処：**
現在、formではinlineformset_factoryを使用している為、ModelFormに変更。
変更後に、初期値が渡されなかった為、断念致しました。

**form.py 変更後**

```
class FormationCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in self.fields.values():
            field.widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'

    class Meta:
        model =  Formation
        fields='__all__'
```

**views.py　変更後**

```
formationform = FormationCreateForm(request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=player)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid() and skillformset.is_valid() and abilityformset.is_valid() and formationform.is_valid():
        form.save()
        skillformset.save()
        abilityformset.save()
        formationform.save()
        # 編集ページを再度表示
        return redirect('mainapp:index')
```

**edit.html　変更後**

```
<h5 class="card-title text-center">フォーメーション編集</h5>
<table class="profile_table mb-4">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="header">フォーメーション画像</th>
      <td class="data">{{ formationform.formation_images }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**※追加※views.pyの各種formをデバッグ表示**

**デバッグ表示の為、viewsを変更**

```
def editformview(request, pk):
    player = get_object_or_404(Player, pk=pk)
    form = PlayerCreateForm(request.POST or None,
                            files=request.FILES or None, instance=player)
    skillformset = SkillInlineFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=player)
    abilityformset = AbilityFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=player)
    formationformset = FormationFormSet(
        request.POST or None, files=request.FILES or None, instance=player)
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        player = form.save(commit=False)
        logging.debug(player)
        if skillformset.is_valid():
            skill = skillformset.save(commit=False)
            logging.debug(skill)
            if abilityformset.is_valid():
               ability = abilityformset.save(commit=False)
               logging.debug(ability)
               if formationformset.is_valid():
                   formationformset.save()
                   player.save()
                   skill.save()
                   ability.save()
                   logging.debug(formationformset)
                   
                   return redirect('index')　＃redirect先が誤っていた為、変更
```

**views変更後のコンソール表示**

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 04, 2022 - 13:20:57
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'e_football2022.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[04/Jan/2022 13:21:02] "GET /detail/1/editform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52473
[04/Jan/2022 13:21:07] "GET /detail/1/editform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52473　
2022-01-04 13:21:13,095 DEBUG キリアン・ムバッペ　　　　　　　⇦　＃　logging.debug(player)
[04/Jan/2022 13:21:13] "POST /detail/1/editform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52114
```

Comment: いずれも古い記事ですが、これらを参考に動作状況を追跡してみては？ [Django - How can I debug code which POST's when a bug seems to be in the view?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40684756/9014308), [Djangoのコンソールにデバッグのメッセージを出力する方法](https://qiita.com/NoriakiOshita/items/7716c6e46338768467eb)

Comment: kunifさん
ご回答ありがとうございます。

ご教示頂いたデバッグ表示について、どのform.save()でエラーが発生しているか確認を行う為、views内容を変更致しました。
※変更内容は、上記質問欄で追記致しました。

確認の結果、「logging.debug(player)」は、表示されましたが、その後は結果表示されなかった為、やはり「skillformset」で問題が発生しているということになりますでしょうか、、、？

改めてご教示頂けると幸いです。
宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

※解決方法
**errorform内容の確認 views.py**

```
if skillformset.is_valid():
    pass
else:
    print(skillformset.errors)
```

**エラー内容**

```
[{'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}, {}, {}, {}]
[04/Jan/2022 21:46:06] "POST /detail/1/editform/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52114
```

**解決方法 editform.html**
参考文献：
https://teratail.com/questions/283685#reply-403501

```
<h5 class="card-title text-center">スキル編集</h5>
<table class="profile_table mb-4">
  <tbody>
    {{ skillformset.management_form }}
    {% for skill_form in skillformset %}
    <tr>
      <th class="header">{{ skill_form.id }}</th> ＃追加
      <td class="data">{{ skill_form.skill }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if skillformset.is_valid():
```

ここのコードは実行してないため、skillformset のデータに不備があるはずなので、
この if に以下の else を追加して、エラー情報を出力してみてください。

```
else:
   print(skillformset.errors.as_text())
```

Comment: steptodreamさん
※コメント編集頂いた　cubickさん

ご回答ありがとうございます。
アドバイス頂いてからも色々と調べましたが、
保存することに成功致しました！！
本当にありがとうございます。

改善方法については、改めて上記質問事項にて載せたいと思いますが、
「print(skillformset.errors)」実施後、[{'id': ['このフィールドは必須です。'], '__all__': ['この Player と Skill を持った Player-skill の関連 が既に存在します。']}というエラーが発生し、editform.htmlのskillformset出力時に{{.skill_form.id }}を追加することで、解決致しました。